# inline figure with caption in actual figure bottom

Tags: floats, captions

I'm expecting the `inline figure` caption should print in `actual figure bottom`. But `inline` figure is not supporting `caption` and how to print the `caption` is withing `bottom of the figure`. my MWE is:

![enter image description here][1]

```
\documentclass{book}
\usepackage{graphics,lipsum,caption}

\begin{document}
\chapter{Chapter Title}

\lipsum[1]
\includegraphics{image-a}
%\caption{The Roman numerals on this stone show how many miles it is from a town}
\lipsum[3]

\end{document}
```

Answer (score 4, accepted):

[image]

```
\documentclass{book}
\usepackage{graphicx,lipsum,caption}

\begin{document}
\chapter{Chapter Title}

\lipsum[1]
\begin{center}
\includegraphics[width=.7\textwidth]{example-image-a}%
\kern-.7\textwidth
\parbox[b]{.7\textwidth}{%
The Roman numerals on this stone show how many miles it is from a town}
\end{center}
\lipsum[3]

\end{document}
```

Comment: How to put the `caption text` in the `shadow box`.

Comment: @Balaji you didn't mention shadow box in the question. It isn't clear what you mean, perhaps use `\colorbox{yellow}{\parbox...`  to put a background to the text?